# jpeg to h.263 or another video format

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have got a Bluetooth application on android that sends jpeg to PC. I want to convert the jpeg to h.263 or any other video format and send the video stream via bluetooth.Is it possible to convert the streaming jpeg images to video format on Android or PC ?

Comment: do you want to create a slideshow ?? or all jpeg images are continuous frames in any video ??

Comment: no.i want to actually convert the jpeg to video so that i can stream that stream as input to video chat in skype or google video chat

Comment: your question is little bit confusing. can you explain it clearly ?

Comment: my PC application receives bytes of jpeg image from my Android application over bluetooth. I want to convert these JPEG images to any video stream.

Comment: where is video chat app, in android device or PC ??

Comment: in PC ... or is it possible to create an application that can send these images to the skype video chat ?

Answer (score 0):

I found one Windows application to convert jpeg images into Video format. Check this software, it may help you.
[JPGVideo Download](http://www.snapfiles.com/downloads/jpgvideo/dljpgvideo.html)